# Hashmap is unable to be added to a collecitons.singletonmap

Tags: java, hashmap

```
import java.util.*;

public class Hash_Map_Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> userEmails = new HashMap<>();
        userEmails.put("abc@gmail.com", "abc");

        Map<String, String> toEmails = Collections.singletonMap("key", "Value");
        toEmails.putAll(userEmails);
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to run the above code, I'm encountering the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:209)
    at java.util.AbstractMap.putAll(AbstractMap.java:281)
    at Hash_Map_Demo.main(Hash_Map_Demo.java:13)
```

I understand that here I'm trying to add a `Hashmap` to `Collections.singletonmap`.
But aren't they same and what is happening behind.

Comment: Well, it's a *singleton* map that holds a *single* entry and is therefore immutable. Refer to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap(K,V))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collections.singletonMap()` returns an immutable map. Use some other `Map` implementation, for example:

```java
HashMap<String, String> toEmails = new HashMap();
toEmails.put("key", "Value")

Map<String, String> userEmails = new HashMap<>();
userEmails.put("abc@gmail.com", "abc");

toEmails.putAll(userEmails);
```

Comment: Or just `HashMap<String, String> toEmails = new HashMap<>(); toEmails.put("key", "Value"); toEmails.put("abc@gmail.com", "abc");` without the unnecessary second map.

Answer (score 1):

The map returned from `Collections.singletonMap()` is immutable so you cannot modify it after creation:

```java
/**
 * Returns an immutable map, mapping only the specified key to the
 * specified value.  The returned map is serializable.
 *
 * @param <K> the class of the map keys
 * @param <V> the class of the map values
 * @param key the sole key to be stored in the returned map.
 * @param value the value to which the returned map maps {@code key}.
 * @return an immutable map containing only the specified key-value
 *         mapping.
 * @since 1.3
 */
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> singletonMap(K key, V value) {
    return new SingletonMap<>(key, value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, got a better understanding about singletonMap

Comment: What if I told you that [there’s an official documentation for the entire API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap(K,V))…

Comment: Well, the meaning is the same :)

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.singletonMap()` returns a `SingletonMap`. This is an implementation of `Map` but do not support `put` method. When the `SingletonMap.putAll` is called, it then calls `SingletonMap.put` and then throws an Exception. This is the reason why it's `immutable`.